# Are there cases where malicious scripts on websites breached the sandbox of a browser so that files on the user's computer could be accessed?

Tags: web-browser, attacks, javascript, sandbox, websites

Whenever a hosted script on a website tries to access a file on a user's computer the sandbox prevents it, but has there been any documented case where this sandbox obstacle was somehow overcome by the script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To keep you up-to date, you can read about the freshly [MFSA2015-78](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2015-78/) where **Firefox** sandboxing mechanism is bypassed by violating the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The problem  fixed by Mozilla Firefox on the 6th of August 2015. This vulnerability allows attackers to bypass the same-origin policy and execute malicious JS code remotely that will be interpreted in the local file context. This, in turn, allows attackers to read and write files on local machine as well as upload them to a remote server.

Attacks exploiting this vulnerability impacts Windows, Linux and OS X operating systems.

The malicious script violates Firefox sandboxing mechanism by exploiting vulnerabilities of the embedded PDF.js in Firefox.

For example, in Windows OS, the script probes important configuration files to fetch, mainly for credentials. A part of its code looks like this:

[image]

You can see the list of the files in which it is interested once your browser is compromised by it.

For **Internet Explorer**, you may read about [CVE-2015-0016](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-0016) released by the end of January 2015. The vulnerability is lead by [TSWbPrxy.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee351720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is an ActiveX Control module. The vulnerability allows the attack to bypass [Internet Explorer sandbox](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-14/materials/Yason/WP-Asia-14-Yason-Diving-Into-IE10s-Enhanced-Protected-Mode-Sandbox.pdf) as it is possible to perform remote attack to gain privileges via a crafted pathname in an executable file.

For **Google Chrome**, you can read about the freshly [CVE-2015-1252](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-1252) in which the sandbox is violated since it is possible for *remote attackers to bypass a sandbox protection mechanism or cause a denial of service (out-of-bounds write) via vectors that trigger a write operation with a large amount of data*

Answer (score -1):

It happened a few times during [this year's Pwn2Own contest](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/17/03/21/2330222/microsofts-edge-was-most-hacked-browser-at-pwn2own-2017-while-chrome-remained-unhackable).

Not only that! One team *additionally* escaped a virtual machine that was running the browser. More details [here](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/03/hack-that-escapes-vm-by-exploiting-edge-browser-fetches-105000-at-pwn2own/).

Comment: link-only answers are only as useful as the lifetime of the link - please include the relevant details from the links in your answer